# A way to acces class variable made in main

Tags: c++, function, class

is there a way to acces class variables made in main function outside it? I tried to make global class variable, but I still can't acces it in other functions.
this is a example how I'd like it to look:

```
x character;

class x{
public:
   int position;

   void write(){
      cout<<position;
     };
}

void show(){
  cout<<character.write;
}

main(){
   character.position = 1;

   show();
}
```

I don't think it's a good idea to show the actual code, cuz it's pretty long and variables are in my language

EDIT: I think I might have a bit miss explained what I meant to do, my goal is to use a method in an outside function.

Comment: ***is there a way to acces class variables made in main function outside it?*** You need to pass the variable to the function that you want to give access. `int main()` is no different from any other function. You should read the chapter in your book covering variable scope. [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c/](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c/)

Comment: Try taking that example and turn it into an actual program. Then if you encounter problems, update this question with the actual problem and your example code.

Comment: Could anyone read the question once more? I did edit it a bit to be more clear what I  wanted to ask

Comment: What do you mean by "can't access it in other functions"? Are you getting errors? If so, please include the full error message in the post

Comment: I see, I wanted to make the program a bit more "tidy" but I see it isn't that easy, thank you guys anyway

Comment: A global variable could be accessible in any function of your program. Although it's not recommend to use global variables.

Comment: @ForceBru I'm not getting any error, the program just doesn't want to start and crashes

Comment: Could be static initialization order fiasco. [http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/static-init-order.html](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/static-init-order.html)

Comment: Im pretty sure this is not the case

Comment: You probably need to figure this out with your debugger and breakpoints. If there is a constructor in your global class, is the constructor executed before the object is accessed?